# VM Jellyfin files not seen

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, mediaserver

I have `Jellyfin` installed in `Ubuntu 22.04` VM. It works fine inside and outside VM and I can access the folders (libraries) through `Android TV`. But the files inside are not listed.

I have an automount, full access shared folder using which I can put files inside VM. I have an `mp3` file in the `Music` folder of VM and I have also set the `shared_folder` as a library.

Even with both `shared_folder` and `Home` of VM as libraries inside `Jellyfin`, I cannot get the files listed inside `Jellyfin`.

I can easily add files to the VM, any folder. But they are not listed inside Jellyfin UI.

Not sure where things are wrong. I guess it is about permissions. Any help will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
sudo chown myname:myname -R home
```

I was able to set permissions as I please afterwards. I allowed read permissions for all. It worked.

myname = myUserName